Surface gradient over triangle
I want to calculate the surface gradient $\nabla_S f=\nabla f-(\vec{n}\nabla f)\vec{n}\,$ of the scalar function $f$ over a triangle in 3D. The triangle is given by the vertices $(\vec{P}_1,\vec{P}_2,\vec{P}_3)$ and the surface is parameterized as $\vec{x}(\eta,\xi)=(\vec{P}_3-\vec{P}_1)\eta+(\vec{P}_2-\vec{P}_1)\xi+\vec{P}_1$. The values of the function $f$ are known at the vertices and are called $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$. The function is assumed to be linear accross the triangle i.e. it can be parameterized as $f(u_1,u_2)=(f_3-f_1)u_1+(f_2-f_1)u_2+f_1$.
I've got the following equation for the surface gradient:
$$
\nabla_S f=\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_2}\right]\left((\textbf{M}\textbf{M}^T)^{-1}\textbf{M}\right)\\
\textbf{M}=\left[\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial \eta},\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial \xi}\right]^T=[\vec{P}_3-\vec{P}_1,\vec{P}_2-\vec{P}_1]^T
$$
but I don't know if this is correct. This seems to be the same equation as stated here but I don't understand how it is derived. Is my equation for the surface gradient correct? If so, how is it obtained? If not, how could the surface gradient be calculated in this case?
Thanks!
